# Android - Keep aspect ratio on background image on default Button

Tags: android, button, background, aspect-ratio

Is there any way to maintain the aspect ratio of a drawable when applied as background on a `Button` (cannot use `ImageButton` (need possibility for text on the `Button`), cannot use `setCompoundDrawables()`, because that also doesn't meet my requirements (I made my own class to support adding backgrounds while still retaining the original android default button, plus I need to set te background in the middle of the button, not left, right, top or bottom)).

I tried a solution with a `ScaleDrawable`, but either I'm doing something wrong or it doesn't work:

```
Bitmap scaled = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(original, (int)newBmpWidth, (int)newBmpHeight, false);
BitmapDrawable bd = new BitmapDrawable(scaled);
ScaleDrawable sd = new ScaleDrawable(bd, Gravity.CENTER, a, b);
//for a and b I tried lots of different values, ranging from 0.07f to 1000
sd.setLevel(1);
```

Then I use the `ScaleDrawable` as background, but it get stretched anyway.

I also tried a `InsetDrawable`, but again, either I'm doing something wrong or it doesn't work, expecting the first:

```
BitmapDrawable mBitmapDrawable = new BitmapDrawable(mBitmap);
InsetDrawable mInsetDrawable = new InsetDrawable(mBitmapDrawable, mLeftOffset, 0, mRightOffset, 0);
```

Then I use the `InsetDrawable` as background, but this also get stretched anyway.

**Is there any way to apply a background but maintain aspect ratio on a `Button`?** I can find plenty answers for `ImageButtons`, but sadly a `Button` does not have a `setImageBitmap()` or `setScaleType()` method.

Comment: what is the resolution(in pixels) of your image? and do you want `Button`'s default background too?

Comment: @Gagan That depends, from what I've tried, several between 40x30 and 256x256 pixels. And yes.

Comment: Generally `Button`s' width vary but the height remains constant. So it'll be quite difficult to keep the aspect ratio of your image intact.

Comment: @Gagan Well, an ImageButton can do all of above, including scaling and maintaining aspect ratio, but I can't apply text on those. I'm trying now if i can just draw the text onto the canvas and make it ImageButtons

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same problem recently for setting the background image of an `ImageView`. The solution I came up with works with any `View`, so it should cover `Button` as well.

The issue is that `View` always stretches its background to the full extent of `View`'s width and height, no matter the scaling of the Drawable provided as background. As your report on failing to provide specialized Drawables suggests, this cannot be counteracted by any means of scaling an image prior to setting it as background because `View` would simply take the image dimensions, whatever they are, and scale them again independently to fill the `View`'s area.

My solution takes a different approach based on the fact that if we can provide a background image with same aspect ratio as the `View`'s, there would be no distortion.

Function `scaleKeepingAspect()` below takes an image resource and answers a `BitmapDrawable` that contains the original image scaled to a desired width and height. The scaling is performed in a way that the aspect ratio of the original image is kept, and eventual remaining spaces to fit the desired box are filled with transparent pixels. The original image is centered in the result image.

```
private BitmapDrawable scaleKeepingAspect(Resources res, int id, int dstWidth, int dstHeight) {

    Bitmap b = (new BitmapFactory()).decodeResource(res, id);
    float scaleX = (float) dstWidth / b.getWidth();
    float scaleY = (float) dstHeight / b.getHeight();
    float scale = scaleX < scaleY ? scaleX : scaleY;
    int sclWidth = Math.round(scale * b.getWidth());
    int sclHeight = Math.round(scale * b.getHeight());
    b = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(b, sclWidth, sclHeight, false);
    int[] pixels = new int[sclWidth * sclHeight];
    b.getPixels(pixels, 0, sclWidth, 0, 0, sclWidth, sclHeight);
    b = Bitmap.createBitmap(dstWidth, dstHeight, b.getConfig());
    b.setPixels(pixels, 0, sclWidth, (dstWidth - sclWidth) / 2, (dstHeight - sclHeight) / 2, sclWidth, sclHeight);
    return new BitmapDrawable(res, Bitmap.createBitmap(b));

}
```

A proper place to make use of `scaleKeepingAspect()` in setting the background of a `View` is during layout change events, so the background is updated properly when the bounds of the `View` change due to layout processing. To do so, assuming (a) your `View` is identified by `myView` in your layout xml, and (b) your background image is file `res/drawable/background.png`, do the following:

1. Declare your `Activity` as an implementor of `View.OnLayoutChangeListener` interface:

   ```
   public class MyActivity extends Activity implements View.OnLayoutChangeListener {

       ...

   }
   ```
2. Register your `Activity` as a listener to layout changes of your `View`:

   ```
   @Override public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

       ...

       myView = (View) findViewById(R.id.myView);
       myView.addOnLayoutChangeListener(this);

       ...

   }
   ```
3. Detect for `View` layout updates in the layout change handler, and update its background when needed:

   ```
   @Override public void onLayoutChange (View v,
           int left, int top, int right, int bottom,
           int oldLeft, int oldTop, int oldRight, int oldBottom) {

       if (left == right || top == bottom || (
               left == oldLeft && top == oldTop &&
               right == oldRight && bottom == oldBottom))
           return;

       switch (v.getId()) {

           case R.id.myView:

               v.setBackground(
                   scaleKeepingAspect(
                       getResources(),
                       R.drawable.background,
                       v.getWidth(),
                       v.getHeight()));
               break;

       }

   }
   ```

Comment: This worked for me, but the result was really pixellated. Nice code, though.

Comment: Good to know; it seems createScaledBitmap, as being used, favors speed instead of quality. (In my tests I didn't notice pixellation; perhaps because I worked with high resolution images at the time?) Anyway you may want to change the filter parameter to true and see if it improves your results.