# How to set background image scale type of a theme?

Tags: android, background-image, scaletype

I'm using a potrait photo as the background image of my application. but when the orientation changes, the background image is streched and ugly. I dont want the image to fit XY .. instead of that, I want it to be centerCropped .. remember , its not a background image of any linear layout. its the background of application(theme) .

I think this is possible, I've seen contact+ to do this in their app..  But I don't know how do they do it. Can anybody help me out please?

NOTE: I have used  and gravity   but it doesn't help.. The image is still fitting XY.not getting cropped to keep its aspect ratio with filling the window as well .

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6782294/android-crop-background

Comment: Are you sure you need to use a background image?  Can you just use an ImageView with scaleType=centerCrop?

Comment: no, you didn't get me. Yes , I can use framelayout to  cover up  whole screen and use that as background. but that doesn't change the background of titlebar/actionbar . (I'm using holo theme) .

So I need background image.

Answer (score 0):

Is the background image of your app being set either by `android:background="..."` in your layout xml,
or programmatically by calling `setBackgroundResource()`?
If so, this sets the background resource of a `View`.

A `View`'s background always stretches to fill up all of the `View` 
width and height, losing its aspect ratio when layout dimensions change
such as when device orientation moves or 
when the application runs in devices
with other screen aspect ratios. There is no way of configuring this
to happen otherwise.

Workarounds:

- Convert your background to a [Nine-Patch](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#NinePatch) file, in order to the
  stretching is
  applied in selected areas of the image only. This may or may not fit well
  to the design of your app.
- Make your application detect changes in your layout. When it happens,
  build a new background image on-the-fly keeping the aspect ratio of the original image, and set the `View`'s background to the new image.
  I've posted 
  a description on how to [keep aspect ratio of View background image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13158305/android-keep-aspect-ratio-on-background-image-on-default-button/35875150#35875150)
  using this technique; hopefully it can serve as a starting point.